# Azure SignalR InvokeAsync hangs when attempting to establish Group connection

Tags: signalr, azure-signalr

Calling InvokeAsync on a connection hangs.

I'm referencing the following [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/groups?view=aspnetcore-5.0) to configure a group connection in Azure SignalR.

NOTE:

I am only able to establish a connection when NOT relying on a group configuration.

**Client:**

```
var negotiateJson = await _client.GetStringAsync($"{host}{"negotiatefn"}");
var negotiate     = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NegotiateInfo>(negotiateJson);

var connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
    .AddNewtonsoftJsonProtocol()
    .WithUrl(negotiate.Url, options => options.AccessTokenProvider = async () => negotiate.AccessToken)
    .Build();

connection.Closed -= Connection_Closed;
connection.Closed += Connection_Closed;

connection.On<JObject>(hubMethodName, OnCourierUpdate);

await connection.StartAsync();
await connection.InvokeAsync("JoinGroup", sessionId); // HANGS APP HERE !!!
```

**Server: Azure Function**

```
public static class LocationFn
{
    [FunctionName(nameof(LocationFn))]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(
            AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous,
            "post",
            Route = nameof(LocationFn))]
        HttpRequest req,
        [SignalR(HubName = "LocationHub")]
        IAsyncCollector<SignalRMessage> signalRMessages,
        ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation($"{nameof(LocationFn)} has been invoked.");

        try
        {
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(req.Body))
            {
                var json = await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync();
                var subjectLocation = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SubjectLocation>(json);

                await signalRMessages.AddAsync(
                    new SignalRMessage
                    {
                        Target    = "LocationUpdate",
                        GroupName = subjectLocation.SessionId,
                        Arguments = new[] { subjectLocation }
                    });

                var message = Log(log, subjectLocation);

                return new OkObjectResult(message);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return new BadRequestObjectResult("There was an error: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
}



public static class JoinGroupFn
{
    [FunctionName(nameof(JoinGroupFn))]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(
            AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous,
            "post",
            Route = nameof(JoinGroupFn))]
        HttpRequest req,
        [SignalR(HubName = "LocationHub")]
        IAsyncCollector<SignalRMessage> signalRMessages,
        ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation($"{nameof(JoinGroupFn)} has been invoked.");

        try
        {
            var groupId = await req.ReadAsStringAsync();

            await signalRMessages.AddAsync(
                new SignalRMessage
                {
                    Target    = "JoinGroup",
                    GroupName = groupId,
                    Arguments = new[] { groupId }
                });

            log.LogInformation($"{nameof(JoinGroupFn)} {groupId}");

            return new OkObjectResult(groupId);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return new BadRequestObjectResult("There was an error: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

**Server: Hub**

```
type LocationHub() as x =

    inherit Hub()

    let this = (x :> Hub)

    member x.LocationUpdate(v:SubjectLocation) =

        async { do! this.Clients.Group(v.SessionId).SendAsync("LocationUpdate", v) |> Async.AwaitTask

              } |> Async.StartAsTask

    member x.JoinGroup(groupId:string) =

        async { do! this.Groups.AddToGroupAsync(this.Context.ConnectionId, groupId) |> Async.AwaitTask

              } |> Async.StartAsTask
```

Comment: Honestly the only time Ive seen the app hang is when the server is not reachable. Are you sure the url is correct? or if the server is hosted over https then the ssl certificate is valid.

Comment: I believe the URL is correct because I can successfully demo a connection WITHOUT a group configuration.

Comment: This looks a bit confusing. Are you using Azure functions or are you using the SignalR library? It looks like you're mixing both on the server side?

Comment: @davidfowl I'm using both.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67624175/unable-to-connect-to-an-azure-signalr-serverlesshub-instance

Comment: So this current question isn't valid and the new question is using the serverless hub right? That is a supported scenario, this question mixes them in an unsupported way.

Answer (score 0):

Im from Azure SignalR team, your service is running in `Serverless` mode, it do not allow any server connection, how can your F# hub run?

And in client side, `connection.InvokeAsync` require server ack, since the server connection can not connected, it cannot get any ack from service.

If you need hub server, please switch the service to `Default` mode, then run hub with Azure SignalR SDK, and verify the server is connected (by log or connection count in service metrics).

If you want serverless, please remove the hub, you can add a Serverless hub in Functions side, see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-concept-serverless-development-config#class-based-model.
And do not forget to set the upstream, see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/concept-upstream#rule-settings.

Comment: I am able to establish a connection between client and server when there is NOT a group configuration.

Comment: yeah, you can connect client, because you use function to handle the negotiate, and it redirect to the service.

But, the hub is not work.

if you write the hub inside of function app, the function do not know anything about hub, it will be treated as a normal class and no one use it.
if you write the hub inside of another app service, and use Azure SignalR SDK, the server connection will be decline, since your service is in serverless mode.

Comment: I think you leave the upstream empty in your service, that will cause the service always ignore all messages from clients.